# I am looking for a way to connect to my database from my laptop, this database is on CPANEL, and i am making a Django Project

Tags: python, mysql, django

Basically what I want to achieve is that,
I have a Django project. and I want to store the db of the project on my Server(CPanel). and access it from the Laptop. I tried searching about Remote MySql on Django but couldnt find anything,
I am not using Google Cloud or PythonAnywhere, or heroku,
is there a way? Please.
Thanks.

Comment: Look up ssh tunnel to mysql.

Comment: okay i found this [https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/create-an-ssh-tunnel-for-mysql-remote-access/] 
I will try this, but i'll have to manually run Sql Commands to update the table or will it work with the Django App?
What hostname should i change to in my Django Settings.py to access the db frm there?
I use Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to access DB remotely on the CPanel of a Virtual server, remote access should be enabled. In my experience, providers close remote connections on VServers unless you ask them to open them. if they open it, you can use putty or similar software to connect to the server and run DB commands.